# Using Kazoo to interact with a ZK cluster

Tags: apache-zookeeper, kazoo

I'm using a ZooKeeper cluster including 5 hosts. To interact with this cluster I will try to code some sort of a proxy using kazoo.

My question is that should i run these proxys on each host in the cluster by initializing the kazoo client object as

`zk = ZooKeeperClient(hosts="127.0.0.1:9999"`)

or

should i use only one proxy to interact with all the cluster nodes by initializing the kazoo client object as

`zk = ZooKeeperClient(hosts="host1,host2,...")`

Is there any difference?